# SSE code to find maximum of array of integers

Tags: c++, sse

I am working on optimizing my c++ code to write in to SSE instructions.

I am working on the loop where we are. finding the max of vector.

```
void findMax(vector<UInt64> & index)
        auto size = index.size();
        Uint64_t max_val = index[0];
        
       for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i)
            max_val = std::max(max_val, index[i]);

}
```

I am trying this way :

```
{
  auto size =  index.size();  

  const auto bytes_sse = sizeof(__m128i);

  const __m128i * data = reinterpret_cast<const __m128i *>(&index);
  __m128i max = reinterpret_cast<const __m128i *>(index[0]);

  const  auto loop_count_sse = (sizeof(index[0])*size)/bytes_sse;

            for(size_t j=0;j<loop_count_sse;j++){
                   max = _mm_max_epi16(max, data+i);
                data += bytes_sse;
            }
```

but this is not working,Please help

Comment: _"but this is not working"_ please elaborate in order to get helped.

Comment: `_mm_max_epi16` works on `int16_t` data.  There is no `_mm_max_epu64` until AVX512, although you could emulate it with SSE4.2 `_mm_cmpgt_epi64` and an XOR to range-shift to unsigned, and pblendvb or something.  Some compilers may vectorize your `std::max` loop, although probably choose not to unless at least AVX2 is available.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cGzbaYao9 yup, GCC and clang auto-vectorize with `-O3 -march=haswell`, but choose not to with SSE2.  Once I fixed the syntax errors in your code, like missing `{` at the start of the function, and defined both `UInt64` and `Uint64_t` as `uint64_t`.

Comment: If you want to iterate over vector contents, you should convert `&index[0]` (pointer to vector contents), not `&index` (pointer to vector struct), to `__m128` pointer. Also, make sure this pointer is aligned to 16 bytes (128 bits).